# jinja2: passing a string as a parameter to a macro?

Tags: macros, jinja2, parameter-passing

I have the following python code to invoke `jinja2`. In this code, I want to pass a string as an argument to a macro ...

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import jinja2

test_template = '''
{% macro testmacro(start, arg1, arg2, arg3) -%}
start_{{arg1}}_{{arg2}}_{{arg3}}
{%- endmacro %}

result = {{ testmacro('begin', A, B, C) }}

'''

template = jinja2.Template(test_template)
rendered = template.render(dict(A='AAA', B='BBB', C='CCC'))

print(rendered)
```

The result is `start_AAA_BBB_CCC`. However, I want it to be `begin_AAA_BBB_CCC`.

And if I call the macro with `'xyz'` as its first parameter, then I want the output to be `xyz_AAA_BBB_CCC`.

I don't want the first parameter to be passed to `jinja2` from the caller as another variable. I want it hard-coded inside of the template, itself, as a parameter to the macro call.

How can I do this in `jinja2` ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, never mind. The answer is simple:

```
{% macro testmacro(start, arg1, arg2, arg3) -%}
{{start}}_{{arg1}}_{{arg2}}_{{arg3}}
{%- endmacro %}
```

I thought I tried that before, and it didn't work, but I must have made some other error that I didn't realize.

As long as the string argument is passed within quotes, this works.